# ActionView::Template::Error: 785: unexpected token at ''

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, continuous-integration, ruby-on-rails-6, webpacker

This error happens randomly during testing (standard Rails testing toolkit) after running `rails test`. Failed test can be any test in any file.

This error happens usually in testing environment during CI/CD process. Locally it occurs very rarely.

Here is a full stack trace:

```
Error:
SitePositionsControllerTest#test_should_create_position_link:
ActionView::Template::Error: 785: unexpected token at ''
    app/views/layouts/site/application.html.erb:10
    test/controllers/site_positions_controller_test.rb:28:in `block (2 levels) in <class:SitePositionsControllerTest>'
    test/controllers/site_positions_controller_test.rb:27:in `block in <class:SitePositionsControllerTest>'
    test/test_helper.rb:64:in `block (3 levels) in run'
    test/test_helper.rb:63:in `block (2 levels) in run'
    test/test_helper.rb:62:in `block in run'
    test/test_helper.rb:54:in `run'

rails test test/controllers/site_positions_controller_test.rb:18
```

Comment: I have encountered such before, there is actually nothing wrong with your code. you could remove that test section.

Comment: Most of the times I got that error it was related to json parsing or malformed javascript. What's on your application layout at line 10?

Comment: @arieljuod it's this line: `<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/favicon-16x16.png">`

Comment: @NsikanSylvester removing test section is not going to help, it occurs randomly for any test. My problem is that it fails CI/CD process so I have to restart it.

Comment: I guess the error is pointing to the wrong line. I would try removing most of the code from the template and start adding it back again until I found what's triggering that. I guess it's some javascript error or json parsing error.

Comment: This error is strange for me: i cannot reproduce it on my system. sometimes it fails and other times it suceeds

Comment: I'm also getting this randomly in CI/CD. That line `app/views/layouts/site/application.html.erb:10` generally points to the `javascript_pack_tag` statement, which leads me to believe that there's some sort of race condition between the test and webpack

Comment: This behavior is issued at rails/webpacker and the issue is still open: https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/2860

Answer (score 2):

Like @jellymann I was having this issue on calls to `javascript_pack_tag`.

I added `bin/rails webpacker:compile` before `rails test` and it seems to have resolved the issue.

This was happening pretty regularly. In the two days since I made that change, at least a dozen or so builds have gone off without this error.

Comment: Also seeing the same issue in CI. I already have `rake webpacker:compile` in the workflow before tests are run. Seeing failure only on some runs. While I think the compile is finished before tests start, @jellymann is right that the occasional failure feels like some sort of race condition between those actions.

Comment: Yeah. That sounds like a race condition to me too. FWIW, to others, I have not see this again since I made the above change. ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I used with webmock and VCR.

Solved adding this initializer (some [hints](https://github.com/bblimke/webmock/issues/163#issuecomment-37257333))

```
# config/initializers/webmock.rb
if Rails.env.test?
  require 'webmock'
  WebMock.disable_net_connect!(allow_localhost: true)
end
```